# Is there a way to find addresses of the code sections (.data, .text, etc) at runtime?

Tags: c, windows, x86, portable-executable

I want to write some code that will print the addresses and lengths of each of the code sections in its own process when run. Is there an easy way to do this? I know it is relatively easy to find the location of functions like main using code like `void* main_address = main;`, but I want to find sections like .data and .text and I don't know if I can do the same thing with them when I compile. I am writing this experiment on a Windows system and compiling for the x86 architecture. I know a little x86 assembly if that is necessary for the solution. I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply walk by `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` s

```
void DumpSections()
{
    //PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinth = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)&__ImageBase + reinterpret_cast<PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(&__ImageBase)->e_lfanew);
    if (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pinth = RtlImageNtHeader(&__ImageBase))
    {
        if (ULONG NumberOfSections = pinth->FileHeader.NumberOfSections)
        {
            PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pish = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pinth);

            do 
            {
                DbgPrint("%p %08x %.8s\n", (PBYTE)&__ImageBase + pish->VirtualAddress, pish->Misc.VirtualSize, pish->Name);
            } while (pish++, --NumberOfSections);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to make function calls?  @P__J__'s answer shows a way that can compile into just a RIP-relative `lea` for the compiler to get the address of `_text_start__` into a register, for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes - it’s not clear to me why this is needed and what is the ultimate goal. what i write - simly dump sections from PE as is. so it’s hard to say what will be the best solution here. solution of P__J__ not usefull for link.exe. here exist way based on link.exe megre section with common name before first $ symbol, in a-z order based after $ can define symbols in ".text$a" and ".text$z" for example. but i be use `char text_start[];` and `char text_end[];` for example - which is have zero size, unlike `char text_start;` and `char text_end;`

Comment: Agreed on C types: I suggested using arrays like `extern char text_end[]` in my answer, too.  But an `extern char` compiles the same as long as you never load/store the value, just take the address of the variable.

Comment: @PeterCordes - this is very toolset depended. `extern char x`; give error *LNK2001: unresolved external symbol*. for more control need declare it in extern *asm* file, but  anyway on this way exist problems.. but i be first ask - for what this need at all. based on this probably possible found | select best solution

Comment: Yeah, of course the symbol is defined elsewhere, that's why you use `extern`.  You're using that to get access to symbols the linker defines itself.  (The GNU binutils linker does define some of these symbols on its own, so yes, it's toolchain dependent).  Manually putting labels in a `.asm` file isn't useful for this; you don't control whether or not they're at the start/end of a section.

Comment: @PeterCordes - no, in asm we also can set section name with $ and control by this place

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO. Not only this is idiomatic, it also doesn't depend on what the linker does: The PE sections are easily found by walking the PE header without the need to know them in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the compiler used. This will be about the gcc & binutils.

1. Find your project linker script. The linker script usually has the `.ld` file extension. If there is no linker script your project uses the default one. To see the default linker script you need to pass `-Wl,--verbose`. You will see a lot of information but we are looking for something like this (this is my one):

```
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
/* Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(pei-i386)
SEARCH_DIR("/mingw/mingw32/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/mingw/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Make the virtual address and file offset synced if the alignment is
     lower than the target page size. */
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  . = ALIGN(__section_alignment__);
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
     *(.init)
    *(.text)
    *(SORT(.text$*))
     *(.text.*)
     *(.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.glue_7)
     ___CTOR_LIST__ = .; __CTOR_LIST__ = . ;
            LONG (-1);*(.ctors); *(.ctor); *(SORT(.ctors.*));  LONG (0);
     ___DTOR_LIST__ = .; __DTOR_LIST__ = . ;
            LONG (-1); *(.dtors); *(.dtor); *(SORT(.dtors.*));  LONG (0);
     *(.fini)
    /* ??? Why is .gcc_exc here?  */
     *(.gcc_exc)
    PROVIDE (etext = .);
    PROVIDE (_etext = .);
     *(.gcc_except_table)
  }
  /* The Cygwin32 library uses a section to avoid copying certain data
     on fork.  This used to be named ".data".  The linker used
     to include this between __data_start__ and __data_end__, but that
     breaks building the cygwin32 dll.  Instead, we name the section
     ".data_cygwin_nocopy" and explicitly include it after __data_end__. */
  .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __data_start__ = . ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data2)
    *(SORT(.data$*))
    *(.jcr)
    __data_end__ = . ;
    *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
  }
  .rdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.rdata)
             *(SORT(.rdata$*))
    __rt_psrelocs_start = .;
    *(.rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc)
    __rt_psrelocs_end = .;
  }
  __rt_psrelocs_size = __rt_psrelocs_end - __rt_psrelocs_start;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
  ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = . - __rt_psrelocs_size;
  .eh_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.eh_frame*)
  }
  .pdata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.pdata)
  }
  .bss BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __bss_start__ = . ;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    __bss_end__ = . ;
  }
  .edata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.edata)
  }
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    *(.debug$S)
    *(.debug$T)
    *(.debug$F)
    *(.drectve)
     *(.note.GNU-stack)
     *(.gnu.lto_*)
  }
  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
    See pe.em:sort_sections.  */
    SORT(*)(.idata$2)
    SORT(*)(.idata$3)
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    SORT(*)(.idata$4)
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$5)
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$6)
    SORT(*)(.idata$7)
  }
  .CRT BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___crt_xc_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XC*))  /* C initialization */
    ___crt_xc_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xi_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XI*))  /* C++ initialization */
    ___crt_xi_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xl_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XL*))  /* TLS callbacks */
    /* ___crt_xl_end__ is defined in the TLS Directory support code */
    ___crt_xp_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XP*))  /* Pre-termination */
    ___crt_xp_end__ = . ;
    ___crt_xt_start__ = . ;
    *(SORT(.CRT$XT*))  /* Termination */
    ___crt_xt_end__ = . ;
  }
  /* Windows TLS expects .tls$AAA to be at the start and .tls$ZZZ to be
     at the end of section.  This is important because _tls_start MUST
     be at the beginning of the section to enable SECREL32 relocations with TLS
     data.  */
  .tls BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    ___tls_start__ = . ;
    *(.tls$AAA)
    *(.tls)
    *(.tls$)
    *(SORT(.tls$*))
    *(.tls$ZZZ)
    ___tls_end__ = . ;
  }
  .endjunk BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* end is deprecated, don't use it */
    PROVIDE (end = .);
    PROVIDE ( _end = .);
     __end__ = .;
  }
  .rsrc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) : SUBALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.rsrc)
    *(.rsrc$*)
  }
  .reloc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    *(.reloc)
  }
  .stab BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stab)
  }
  .stabstr BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.stabstr)
  }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section.  Unlike other targets that fake this by putting the
     section VMA at 0, the PE format will not allow it.  */
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_aranges)
  }
  .zdebug_aranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_aranges)
  }
  .debug_pubnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubnames)
  }
  .zdebug_pubnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_pubnames)
  }
  .debug_pubtypes BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_pubtypes)
  }
  .zdebug_pubtypes BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_pubtypes)
  }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
  }
  .zdebug_info BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_info .zdebug.gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
  }
  .debug_abbrev BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_abbrev)
  }
  .zdebug_abbrev BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_abbrev)
  }
  .debug_line BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_line)
  }
  .zdebug_line BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_line)
  }
  .debug_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_frame*)
  }
  .zdebug_frame BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_frame*)
  }
  .debug_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_str)
  }
  .zdebug_str BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_str)
  }
  .debug_loc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_loc)
  }
  .zdebug_loc BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_loc)
  }
  .debug_macinfo BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_macinfo)
  }
  .zdebug_macinfo BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_macinfo)
  }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_weaknames)
  }
  .zdebug_weaknames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_weaknames)
  }
  .debug_funcnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_funcnames)
  }
  .zdebug_funcnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_funcnames)
  }
  .debug_typenames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_typenames)
  }
  .zdebug_typenames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_typenames)
  }
  .debug_varnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_varnames)
  }
  .zdebug_varnames BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_varnames)
  }
  .debug_macro BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_macro)
  }
  .zdebug_macro BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_macro)
  }
  /* DWARF 3.  */
  .debug_ranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_ranges)
  }
  .zdebug_ranges BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_ranges)
  }
  /* DWARF 4.  */
  .debug_types BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.debug_types .gnu.linkonce.wt.*)
  }
  .zdebug_types BLOCK(__section_alignment__) (NOLOAD) :
  {
    *(.zdebug_types .gnu.linkonce.wt.*)
  }
}
```

Copy and paste it to the text file (.ld extension will help you or other people to understand what this file does).

As we see the `.text` section does provide two symbols at the end, but there is no symbol at the beginning. We can add this symbol ourselves:

```
  .text  __image_base__ + ( __section_alignment__ < 0x1000 ? . : __section_alignment__ ) :
  {
     .__text_start__ = .;
     *(.init)
```

You need to pass `-Tpath_to_your_ld_file` to the linker

then in the .c file we can test it:

```
extern char _text_start__, etext, _data_start__, _data_end__, _bss_start__, _bss_end__;

int main()
{
    printf("Text start: %p  Text end: %p\n", (void *)&_text_start__, (void *)&etext);
    printf("Data start: %p  Data end: %p\n", (void *)&_data_start__, (void *)&_data_end__);
    printf("BSS start: %p  BSS end: %p\n", (void *)&_bss_start__, (void *)&_bss_end__);
}
```

on my computer it is:

```
Text start: 00401000  Text end: 00408FF4
Data start: 00409000  Data end: 0040902C
BSS start: 0040D000  BSS end: 0040DA34
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Windows conventions, but if it's like Linux your compiler, assembler, or linker may define a symbol for the start of a section.  (Use `nm` or a similar tool to dump the symbol table from a `.obj` or `.exe`.)

If so, `extern const char that_symbol[]` would define a C variable of a potentially matching name.  Then of course you can just use the address of `that_symbol`.  (Note, not `const char *that_symbol` ; there's no pointer stored in memory.  You're defining a static variable whose *address* is the address you want.  Don't read the *value* of this variable.)

Use GNU C `extern char foo[] asm("real_name")` if needed to work around leading underscores or use an asm symbol name that includes a `.` or something that C doesn't allow.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html  This is of course a GNU extension.

---

**See [@P__J__'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028743/is-there-a-way-to-find-addresses-of-the-code-sections-data-text-etc-at-run/60029074#60029074) for a full Windows implementation of what this answer was suggesting**, including a GNU binutils linker script to add missing symbols for starts/ends of some sections that the toolchain doesn't define on its own.  It uses `extern char` instead of `extern char[]` for the C name, so you have to always use `&name` to take the address of the symbol.  But the fundamental idea of defining C `extern` globals that have the address you want is exactly what I was suggesting.

Comment: Can you explain that trick with putting in the real symbol name with assembly a little more? I have never seen assembly mixed with C on the same line like that before

Comment: OS does matter. toolchain matters

Comment: @kansas_bulldog382: added a link to the GCC manual about that GNU extension.