# Referencing symbols with a leading period in inline assembly

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to reference certain symbols that begin with a period (like .data, .test, etc) using inline assembly in my C program on Windows.

(To implement [Is there a way to find addresses of the code sections (.data, .text, etc) at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028743/is-there-a-way-to-find-addresses-of-the-code-sections-data-text-etc-at-run))

For example, I tried adding the code:

```
void* data_pointer;
__asm { mov data_pointer,.data};
```

And I will get the error: `inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found '.'`

Visual Studio's compiler will not allow leading periods on label names, even in assembly. Is there some way I can get around this on Windows?

Comment: at first no such symbols - `.data` etc

Comment: That wouldn't work even with a valid label name.  You want `mov local_var, OFFSET symbol_name` to get the *address* of a symbol.  x86 instructions can't use 2 explicit memory operands (e.g. you can't `mov` from mem to mem).  Anyway, that probably doesn't help with the symbol name problem; are you sure there's a symbol with that name, and also no other symbol with the same address?  P__J__'s answer on [Is there a way to find addresses of the code sections (.data, .text, etc) at runtime?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60028743) suggests that there are some `_` named symbols.